# How to fix error (0x84bb0001: The system cannot find the file specified) when installing SQL Server 2016 or 2017?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016

I uninstalled SQL Server from computer and then removed folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server".
 After it I tried to install SQL Server 2016 and installation failed with

> "The system cannot find the file specified".

There is log: https://pastebin.com/Y07uvQT9

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
  Exit facility code:            1211
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  The system cannot find the file specified.
```